# Glide is not working in my project

Tags: android, android-glide

I am developing an application in which i am using Glide Library to load image from server. But Unfortunately this is not working and i am completely unaware about this and trying to solve this issue since last two days.

this is my code.

```
Glide.with(this).load(response.getBank_cash_deposit().getData().getAttributes().getAttachment()).into(mSelectedImage);
```

Comment: show me error log

Comment: Update your code here to help

Comment: check your response and image url which you get from server simply copy that url and paste it on web browser and check image is there or not?

Comment: check your image url

Answer (score 0):

Try `Log` your image response. you're getting correct `image URL` or not.
If the `image URL` is correct then check whether there is `space` in your `image URL` or not.
If the space is exists then replace `space` in your `URL String` with `%20` with the help of `string.replace()` function.

```
String image=response.getBank_cash_deposit().getData().getAttributes().getAttachment();

Log.d("Image",image);
```

if space exists
then

```
image.replace(" ","%20");
```

Also check `image url` on web.

Comment: I got my problem skip Memory Cache 



this is my code.

Glide.with(this).load(Uri.parse(response.getBank_cash_deposit().getData().getAttributes().getAttachment()))
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                        .skipMemoryCache(true)
                        .into(mSelectedImage);
                mSelectedImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: @PcPatidar happy coding